# I want to keep the login status of asp.net core always in multiple WAS

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-session

I am developing and testing a local service fabric cluster in a 5-node environment.

I used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

However, if I try to sign-in, I get not signed-in page of 4/5 chance.

I've looked at the documentation and tried several things, but it still does not work.

(ex. AddIdentity, UseAuthentication, AddDistributedRedisCache, AddSession, UseSession)

**What is the simplest way to share a user's authentication status via Redis Session when use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?**

Comment: Do you have shared data protection set up so they can decode shared cookies?

Comment: I did not know exactly, but I also added the following code and I noticed that the DataProtection-Keys value was added via redis-cli.

var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");

Comment: I'm wondering if the value that is compared to the cookie's .AspNetCore.Identity.Application value is stored in the memory of the node machine. In fact, I've also temporarily set up the IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute to prevent Anti-forgery related error.

Comment: I solved it now. I have the services.ConfigureApplicationCookie (..) code, which seems to override the Identity cookie option. I tried a lot of code and made a mistake. DataProtection has already been applied, but I've tried it because of you. Thank you.